# Why is this gsub not working in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to replace every word beginning with Jo with the word Joburg, however this code isn't working and I don't understand why.

```
gsub("^Jo\\w+","Joburg",DF[,4:9])
```

My data frame has 10 columns and i'm looking to do the replacement in columns 4 to 9, all of which are factors.

When I run unique() afterwards i still get the original list of distinct words starting with Jo, instead of only the word Joburg throughout.

Comment: That is both very non-informative and misleading title to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are working on a `data.frame`, then loop through the columns and apply the `gsub`

```
DF[4:9] <- lapply(DF[4:9], function(x) gsub("^Jo\\w+","Joburg",x))
```

This can also be done with `sub` and without an anonymous function call

```
DF[4:9] <- lapply(DF[4:9], sub, pattern = "^Jo\\w+", replacement = "Joburg")
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("Joan", "abf", "Jedi", "acf"), 9*4,
                       replace=TRUE), ncol=9))
```

Comment: thank you that works. However note that I had to change [4:9] to [,4:9].

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to replace content for one column only you can do as follows:

```
data$colname <- gsub ("^Jo\\w+","Joburg", data$colname)
```

you can also convert factor to character if there are too many factors and then use gsub

```
data$column_name <- as.character(data$column_name)
```

Make sure that the library for gsub function is loaded.